# How to prevent InvalidAuthenticityToken Exception when switching from :cookie_store to :active_record_store?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, activerecord, devise, session-store

I'm switching my session store from :cookie_store to :active_record_store.  I've noticed when I first tried to log in I received an `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`.  I'm guessing this is because of the cookie that exists on my computer from the old cookie_store?  After I removed it from my chrome browser settings I was able to log in fine.  I'd like to have a seemless way to keep all of my users from having to delete their cookies before they can log in correctly.  But how would I do this?

Comment: You can invalidate the existing cookies by changing the `secret_key_base`. There is no real way around this. You can't get the session data held by the user in a session cookie magically. Fortunately it only really should require the users to sign in again.

Comment: @max, So I use capistrano to deploy my project.  So if I do the following I should be good? (1) run `rake secret` and copy output, (2) place in `shared/config/secrets.yml` on my server, & (3) redeploy my project to production?

Comment: Yes. I would use an ENV var instead of actually putting it in the file though. `secret_key_base: <%= ENV.fetch('SECRET_KEY_BASE') %>`.

Comment: It allows you to change the configuration without redeploying and safeguards against someone accidentally copying over the file. https://12factor.net/config